# Blank lines from database text not shown in HTML

Tags: html, css, angular, database, typescript

I have the following dataset from my db:

```
description: "Test1
 
              Test2"
```

I tried displaying the data as follows:

```
<div class="font-weight-bold text-dark-75">{{ description }}</div>
```

Result in browser:

```
Test1 Test2
```

What can I do to display the following?

```
Test1

Test2
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a pipe that converts the newlines to `<br>` tags:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'

@Pipe({ name: 'newline' })
export class NewlinePipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(value: string): string {
    return value.replace(/\n\r|\n/g, '<br>')
  }
}
```

Next add the pipe to your module declaration:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [NewlinePipe]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then use the pipe in the template:

```html
<div class="font-weight-bold text-dark-75" [innerHTML]="description|newline"></div>
```